# Shell Script for checking log and running a program

Tags: shell, unix

I have this script that checks the last line of the file `newlog.log` and if it finds the word `Stream closed` there it should run the program test.jar because it would have stopped and hence written `Stream closed` in the log file.

```
#!/bin/sh
SUCCESS=0 
while (true);
do
sleep 5
tail -1 ~newlog.log | grep -q "Stream closed" .
if  [$? -eq 1]
then 
java -jar test.jar &
fi
done
```

The error I get is :

```
run.sh: 11: [1: not found
```

Please tell me if there's some syntax error or what?

Comment: 1 obvious mistake is using 'sleep 5' and 'tail -1' together. What if the same log file is getting updated multiple times? you wouldn't always find "Stream Closed" in the last. Not sure about your design, but keep this in mind :). Also add proper 'spaces' in your if condition, that should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
tail -f file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Exit Status of the grep command, store the output in a variable and loop until it's length is non-zero.

Grep will return exit status of 0 even when it doesn't return any output.

var1=`tail -1 ~newlog.log | grep -q "Stream closed"`

until [ -n "${var1}" ];

do

```
  echo "Sleeping for next 5 seconds"

  sleep 5
```

done

```
java -jar test.jar &
```

Answer (score 0):

The original error '[1' caused by the OP not putting spaces around the square brackets in the if statement.

It seems that the tail command is returning an exit code of 1.
The if statement should be

```
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
```

...

and *not*

```
if [$? -eq 1]
then
```

....